# MYSQL auto update second table query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, primary-key

I am having 2 tables

> Try1 (ID and ValueA )

and

> try2 (ID and valueb)

In table Try1 ID is the Auto increment and Primary key, I somehow want to link this TRY1.ID to try2.ID so that when i `insert into try1 (valueA)=XXX` then the ID that is autogenerated is also reflected in Try2

( Is the solution related to create a foreign key based on the 1st ?)

I am using PHPMYADMIN and php to insert querys. Any possible way would be helpful, Thanks

Comment: Why not just add a column for valueb in the try1 table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for a trigger - something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    /*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
    TRIGGER `CopyTry1RowToTry2` AFTER INSERT ON `try1` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        INSERT INTO `try2` (`id`,`value`) VALUES(NEW.`id`,NEW.`value`)
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: SQL query:

CREATE TRIGGER `CopyTry1RowToTry2` AFTER INSERT ON  `try1` 
FOR EACH
ROW BEGIN 
INSERT INTO  `try2` 
SET ID = NEW.ID;


MySQL said: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: That's a pretty general error, lol.  i'm afraid you'll need to finish up the research to suit your needs - specificaly - just google "mysql trigger example".  I've updated my answer with a variation that ran for me without error

Answer (score 2):

In Try2 mention Try1 ID as foriegn key. Like:

```
CREATE TABLE Try2 (id INT, Try1_id INT, valueb INT,
                    INDEX par_ind (Try1_id),
                    FOREIGN KEY (Try1_id) REFERENCES Try1(id)
                      ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

For more information on foriegn key see this

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: after insertion in try1 when i do a select * from try2  i dont get any result

Comment: Hey it's not like that; I think you getting confused; you don't get the id's automatically in child table rather when you insert in child table you can use the PKID and have that inserted in child table for FK column. If you want, an auto insert to child table then you need a trigger.